# i am Turkish passport holder, travel from new Delhi to Dubai to Istandul, i have to wait 16 hour, but same flight Flydubai, can i travel or not

Tags: transit, transit-visas, dubai, uae, turkish-citizens

I am Turkish passport holder, from new Delhi to Dubai to Istanbul, I have to wait 16 hour,  but same flight Fly Dubai, can I travel or not.

Comment: can you confirm me, wheather i can travel , or need transit visa.

Answer (score 0):

If your transit is less than 24 hours you don't need a visa and can stay in the transit zone given both flights are on the same ticket.